# How do I display names of files that start and end with a certain letter?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, unix, wildcard

I want to display names of files that start with the letter 'a' and end with 'z' in linux shell. I've tried using: `ls *a *z` but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If your quoted command is correct and not a typo, this would search for files starting with 'a' OR 'z', this would be due to the space between the `a*` and the `z*`.

If this is the case and you are trying to find files starting with 'a' and ending in 'z', the correct command would be:

```
ls a*z
```

Comment: `ls [az]*` would list `apple` or `zebra`.

Comment: @Beta my bad, long day ha.

Answer (score 0):

This requirement can also be achieved by the locate command as below,

```
locate "a*z"
```

Though find command is also an efficient one.

Answer (score -1):

```
find . -name "a*z"
```

You can replace "." with any directory name.

Answer (score -1):

I think grep could help you .You can also use `grep [0-9][0-9] file`
or `grep '^\.[a-z][a-z]'` .

Comment: This returns the *lines within the file* that match the regular expression, not the file names. And `[0-9][0-9]` as well as `\.[a-z][a-z]` don't seem to be related to what the question asks for.